# Is the site key from recaptcha considered sensitive?

Tags: recaptcha

I'm curious what, if any precautions I should take to protect the site key. The docs mention the secret key which is used for server-side validation should be considered secret. I'm guessing site key is not sensitive but I really want to make sure.